# multiprocessing.map_async hangs (but multiprocessing.map works correctly)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to parallelize a piece of code in my program.

If I use `multiprocessing.map_async` (or `starmap_async`) the code hangs at `results.get()`.
However if I use `map` (or `starmap`) the code executes correctly. Here is a minimal working example with which I can reproduce this behaviour:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def function(i):
    return i**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('map')
    with Pool(6) as pool:
        result = pool.map(function, range(100))

    print(result)

    print('map_async')
    with Pool(6) as pool:
        result = pool.map_async(function, range(100))

    print('Getting results')
    print(result.get())
```

The code runs (almost instantly) up to the line `print('Getting results')`, then it just hangs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already left the context-manager when you call `print(result.get())`, so the pool is already closed. Indent your prints:

```
with Pool(6) as pool:
    result = pool.map_async(function, range(100))
    print('Getting results')
    print(result.get())  # <--
```